# How to show that level set of a function is closed submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, lie-groups

Question : Let f : M \to N be a smooth map. If the Lie group G acts on both smooth manifolds M and N such a way that its action on M is transitive and for each x \in M and g \in G, we have f(gx)=gf(x), then show that each level set of map f is a closed submanifold.

My attempt :

[image]

I couldn't write the diagram in latex so I uploaded hand writing. Is my solution correct?

Comment: I'm not reading your argument, but level sets of any continuous map are always closed subspaces.

Comment: @TedShifrin you seem not to read the question too

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct, although the last sentence should be replaced by a simpler argument, as Ted suggested.

Comment: No, I read the question. If you're talking about level sets, the group action is irrelevant. Maybe you should clarify things in your own mind and then in the question.

Comment: Here is a short [Commutative Diagram tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16888)

Comment: $ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD} T_{m_0}M@>Df>>T_{f(m_0)}N\\ @VD\theta_{g_0}^1VV@VVD\theta_{g_0}^2V\\ T_{m_1}M@>>Df>T_{f(m_1)}N \end{CD} $ (My first commutative diagram)